# setup/install project assembly redirection to relative directory

Tags: installation, .net-assembly, search-path

I have developed a small installer (target: net 3.5 client profile) and I have two issues.

1. Because this is done with .Net 3.5 Framework and one of my target systems is XP, I have to check if .Net 3.5 Framework is installed or not before I can run the program. So, I used Inno-Setup to check and install the framework if so. I’m not sure if this was the best way to go. I wonder if someone will give me some better option in regard to Inno-Setup choice. I’ve tried windows scripting (*.vbs) but in one of my tests, on XP station, this *.vbs file could not run because this type of files were not associated with Wscript.exe so, I give up from this option.
2. There are few assembly files (dll) that my project uses and, by default, they were dumped to debug/release folders when I compile the project. However I have used some other assembly files that I load dynamically and invoke methods and properties through reflection. I manually, hard coded those files locations relative to my exe files. So, if I have my exe file in a CD (D:) then my program will look for a folder D:\Bin. For win7 it will look for D:\Bin\Win7 and for XP it will look for D:\Bin\XP folders etc. My program uses three common assemblies (described at the beginning) that I loaded through ‘Add References’ before I compile my project and, as I said, VS dumped them into debug/release folders. What I actually needed is to have these files in my Bin folder so my setup.exe file will be alone with config.ini file in the root directory of the CD; nice and clean. What I needed is to tell somehow to VS that I need my assemblies to be in the Bin folder inside the output folder (debug/release). If this is possible then I can COPY my executable with the Bin folder and make CD which is my final goal.

Any better ideas on these two issues?
tnx

Comment: 1) what's wrong with using InnoSetup ? It's definitely better than vbs script (I can't believe they're still alive :-) I'm not saying best, maybe using some .NET magic is better, just comparing InnoSetup with vbs...

Comment: there i nothing wrong with inno-setup. I'm trying to avoid multiple environment/language use in my project. Ideally I was looking something that would work in windows XP (no SP3 or SP1) and up w/out any run-time prior installation. I guess I have to stick with vb.net+inno-setup.